# Android "application stopped unexpectedly" - google Hello MapView Tutoria

Tags: java, android

I'm trying the [Hello MapView Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) at the moment. Whe I launch the program in the emulator, I get a huge number of errors (none of the exceptions seems to be related with lines in my code). The emulator window tells the program "stopped unexpectedly". Can anybody tell me which is the key line in the error output? What do I have to change?

```
05-02 15:04:57.195: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-02 15:04:57.195: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test2' (No such file or directory)
05-02 15:04:57.195: ERROR/vold(26): Error opening switch name path '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-02 15:04:57.195: ERROR/vold(26): Error bootstrapping switch '/sys/class/switch/test' (No such file or directory)
05-02 15:05:10.659: ERROR/MemoryHeapBase(51): error opening /dev/pmem: No such file or directory
05-02 15:05:10.659: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(51): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
05-02 15:05:10.699: ERROR/libEGL(51): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
05-02 15:05:11.403: ERROR/libEGL(62): couldn't load <libhgl.so> library (Cannot load library: load_library[984]: Library 'libhgl.so' not found)
05-02 15:05:14.775: ERROR/BatteryService(51): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/usb/online'
05-02 15:05:14.775: ERROR/BatteryService(51): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_vol'
05-02 15:05:14.775: ERROR/BatteryService(51): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_temp'
05-02 15:05:15.148: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
05-02 15:05:15.148: ERROR/EventHub(51): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51): Failure starting core service
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51): java.lang.SecurityException
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
05-02 15:05:15.282: ERROR/System(51):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:162)
05-02 15:05:15.302: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(51): Crash logging skipped, no checkin service
05-02 15:05:17.012: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(51): Failed to bind to GLS while checking for account
05-02 15:05:21.795: ERROR/ActivityThread(100): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-02 15:05:21.819: ERROR/ActivityThread(100): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-02 15:05:25.872: ERROR/ApplicationContext(51): Couldn't create directory for SharedPreferences file shared_prefs/wallpaper-hints.xml
05-02 15:05:28.923: ERROR/vold(26): Cannot start volume '/sdcard' (volume is not bound)
05-02 15:05:26.879: ERROR/ActivityThread(97): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-02 15:05:30.211: ERROR/ActivityThread(97): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-02 15:05:30.430: ERROR/ActivityThread(97): Failed to find provider info for android.server.checkin
05-02 15:05:32.463: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(30): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound
05-02 15:05:32.489: ERROR/MediaPlayer(51): Unable to to create media player
05-02 15:05:34.783: ERROR/ActivityThread(51): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-02 15:05:34.783: ERROR/ActivityThread(51): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
05-02 15:05:35.359: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{org.diretto.client.smartphone.android/org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4376af90
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4376af90
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     ... 11 more
05-02 15:05:35.527: ERROR/dalvikvm(201): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

> none of the exceptions seems to be
>   related with lines in my code

One most certainly is:

```
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity     ComponentInfo{org.diretto.client.smartphone.android/org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4376af90
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4376af90
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201):     ... 11 more
```

The key line is:

```
05-02 15:05:35.395: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(201): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@4376af90
```

which can be resolved by you implementing the org.diretto.client.smartphone.android.ShowMap class, or ensuring its superclass exists.

Since you are playing with maps, I am going to guess that you are trying this in the Android emulator. Your emulator AVD probably does not have the Google APIs installed, so Android cannot find some map-related superclass of `ShowMap` (e.g., `MapActivity`). Make sure your AVD is one that is not just for Android 2.1 (or whatever), but has the Google APIs in it.